# Find Max Number from array

Tags: php

I have below array:

```
    $a = array(
    1,
    2,
    array(
        10,
        9
    ),
    100,
    array(
        45,
        60,
        array(
            30,
            15
        ),
        100
    )
)
foreach($a as $v)
{
  print_r($v);
}
```

I want to find max numbers?

Comment: What is your actual question? What causes you trouble?

Comment: I want find max number from this array

Answer (score 4):

You can keep track of max in a variable say `$max` and keep storing/overwriting maximum of values in it. If you encounter a value that is an array, then you recursively loop over it and take the maximum of the return value from it too.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$arr = array(1,2,array(10,9),100,array(45,60, array(30,15),100));

function getMax($arr){
    $max = 0;
    $assigned = false;
    foreach($arr as $ele){
        $returned_val = $ele;
        if(is_array($ele)){
            $returned_val = getMax($ele);
        }

        if(!$assigned || $max < $returned_val){
            $max = $returned_val;
            $assigned = true;
        }
    }
    return $max;
}

print_r(getMax($arr));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/6TReQ

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = array(1,2,array(10,9),100,array(45,60,array(30,15),100));

$max = null;
array_walk_recursive($a, function($val) use (&$max)
{
    if($max===null || $val > $max)
        $max = $val;
});

echo $max;
```